# Node app won't run on Azure App Service: Container won't respond, pm2 constantly restarts

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm having a lot of trouble getting a basic Node app to run in Azure App Service. Here are some details on my app:

- JS is compiled from Typescript. I am building the app locally, then zipping the contents and pushing to Azure as a Zip deploy.
- The app is listening on the `PORT` env variable.
- The app runs using pm2. The start script is: `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --no-daemon`.
- pm2 is configured to run in cluster mode.

After deploying the app, I check the logs in Log Stream in the Azure Portal. I see a couple of weird things:

1. The Azure-provided Docker container never responds to a warm up request:

```
2023-12-04T01:26:46.611Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container api-web-app-stg_0_030ed77e. Elapsed time = 413.9951718 sec
2023-12-04T01:27:01.856Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container api-web-app-stg_0_030ed77e. Elapsed time = 429.2399904 sec
2023-12-04T01:27:17.275Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container api-web-app-stg_0_030ed77e. Elapsed time = 444.6587283 sec
2023-12-04T01:27:33.470Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container api-web-app-stg_0_030ed77e. Elapsed time = 460.8540835 sec
2023-12-04T01:27:48.640Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container api-web-app-stg_0_030ed77e. Elapsed time = 476.0234168 sec
2023-12-04T01:28:03.827Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container api-web-app-stg_0_030ed77e. Elapsed time = 491.2109671 sec
...
```

2. The app seems to constantly restart:

```
2023-11-22T22:15:47.864418216Z 22:15:47 PM2      | App [index:0] starting in -fork mode-
2023-11-22T22:15:47.922806005Z 2023-11-22T22:15:47: PM2 log: App [index:0] online
2023-11-22T22:15:47.943170641Z 22:15:47 PM2      | App [index:0] online
2023-11-22T22:16:09.788233299Z 2023-11-22T22:16:09: PM2 log: App [index:0] exited with code [255] via signal [SIGINT]
2023-11-22T22:16:09.788294500Z 22:16:09 PM2      | App [index:0] exited with code [255] via signal [SIGINT]
2023-11-22T22:16:09.788301600Z 2023-11-22T22:16:09: PM2 log: App [index:0] starting in -fork mode-
```

Finally, some things I've tried, based on a lot of research.

1. Set the `WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT` var to 1800, to give the container plenty of time to warm up.
2. Set both the `WEBSITES_PORT` and `PORT` (together and separately) to 8080, to see if that helped the container respond.
3. Ensured that the app runs locally; double-checked pm2 configuration.
4. A bunch of other stuff that I can no longer remember, based on Azure docs and other SO posts. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Node.js sample code, deployed it to the Azure App Service as a web app, and it worked.

Output :
[image]

from **log stream** :
[image]

[image]

Ensure that your startup command in Azure App Service resembles the following:
[image]

Install PM2 in the project using this command:

```
npm install -g pm2
```

I run local code using the following command:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --no-daemon
```

Output :
[image]

Local **PM2** logs:
[image]

Please ensure your port is correct and note the code I am using.
**app.ts**

```js
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;


app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send('Hello, Azure App Service!');
  });
  app.get('/health', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.status(200).send('OK');
  });
  
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
  });
```

**package.json**

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --no-daemon",
    "build": "tsc",
    "prestart": "npm run build"
  },
```

**ecosystem.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    apps: [
      {
        name: 'my-node-app1',
        script: './dist/app.js',
        instances: 1,
        exec_mode: 'fork',  // Corrected value
        autorestart: true,
        watch: true,
        max_memory_restart: '1G',
        env: {
          NODE_ENV: 'development',
          PORT: 8080,
        },
        env_production: {
          NODE_ENV: 'production',
          PORT: 80,
        },
      },
    ],
  };
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true   
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```